# Using functions as input

Tags: python, python-2.7

I've written a program (A) that takes, as input, the names of functions I wrote in a separate program (B). I want to use these functions in program (A), so I am trying to run (A) by doing this: A(f1, f2, f3, f4)

At the top of (A), I imported program (B) using import B. In (A) there is just one function (excluding main) that accepts four inputs (f1, f2, f3, f4), and then uses them, like this:

```
    for i in range(x, y):
       z = B.f1(i)
       u = B.f2(i)
       ...
    ...
```

The trouble is, when I try to run A(f1, f2, f3, f4), I get the error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "<pyshell#0>", line 1, in <module>
      A(f1, f2, f3, f4)
NameError: name 'f1' is not defined
```

I see that python is not recognizing the functions in (B) as input in (A), but I don't know why or how else I can connect the two programs.

Update: Program A

```
def A(f1, f2, f3, f4) :

   x = 0
   y = 10

   for i in range(x, y):
       x = B.f1(i) //returns float
       plt.plot(i, x)
   ...
```

Comment: show us the import statement, but it sounds like you're trying to turn strings into python commands, which is a Bad Thing to do. Show us also how you're calling `A` (from terminal, I assume?)

Comment: My import statement is exactly: import B

Comment: I'm also calling A from idle. I press f5 to run the program, which runs without errors, then try A(f1, f2, f3, f4) and get the error I posted above

Comment: Actually the code snippet from your function body looks rather strange, can you post the entire function definition?

Comment: Sure, I updated my post. I'm trying to plot points using the results from calling user-specified functions in (B) on a range of inputs.

Comment: hmm, so you're sending `f1` as an input to the `A` function, but you're then using `B.f1` in the function itself.  I'm guessing you actually want to use the `f1` that was provided as input for the `A` function, right?

Comment: Yes, I want the user to be able to specify any 4 functions in B: they could do A(f47, f29, f102, f0). But I don't know what functions they want to plot until I receive it as input

Comment: @mdegges how is the user providing those functions? Are you using `raw_input`?

Comment: The user is manually running A in idle and specifying the functions they want graphed.

Comment: @mdegges so you have both `A` defined in the interactive session and `B` is a module saved somewhere on your PYTHONPATH? You've imported into the interactive session `import B`? Your user should then call `A(B.f1, B.f49, B.f100, B.f42)` and your function signature for `A` should look like `def A(func1, func2, func3, func4)`. Inside of `A`, you ALWAYS refer to these as `func1`, `func2`, `func3`, and `func4`

Comment: Thanks for clarifying Adam, I think I jumped the gun a little on posting an answer before getting the full picture.  btw, mdegges, you don't really have a module named B, and functions named A, f1, f2 etc do you?  Non-descriptive names are a root of many bugs...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on a literal reading of your question, if you imported B via

```
import B
```

then every reference to functions, variables, classes etc defined in B must be done in the form `B.func1` etc.

Your error message clearly says that you're trying to do `A(f1, f2, f3, f4)`.  This should be `A(B.f1, B.f2, B.f3, B.f4)`

**EDIT** Judging from your updated question, I'm guessing you want something like:

```
import B

def A(input_function1, input_function2, input_function3, input_function4) :
    x = 0
    y = 10

    for i in range(x, y): #btw, you don't need the x value here if it's 0
        x = input_function1(i) //returns float #I removed the 'B.'
        plt.plot(i, x)
    # Other stuff here

if __name__=='__main__':
    A(B.f1, B.f2, B.f3, B.f4)
    # or alternatively A(B.f78, B.f21, B.f1, B.f90) or whatever
```

Or alternatively:

```
from B import f1, f2, f3, f4

def A(f1, f2, f3, f4) :
    # Stuff here

if __name__=='__main__':
    A(f1, f2, f3, f4) # Explicit imports mean that the 'B.' prefix is unnecessary
```

Comment: Will the alt import the actual f1, f2, f3, and f4 functions from B, or will it import the functions the user specifies when they run the program, using A(f62, f22, f2323, f100)?

Comment: it will be whatever they specify.  Let me rewrite the code to make it clearer.

Comment: inside `A`, it'll use the local `f1` `f2` `f3` and `f4`. Outside it'll use the imported ones. Name them something else to prevent confusion.

Answer (score 0):

To extend what @zehnpaard has already suggested, if you want to call the **B** function in **A()** using **f1...f4** as arguments, you can alternatively use `getattr()`, like this:

```
...
def A(f1, f2, f3, f4) :

   x = 0
   y = 10

   for i in range(x, y):
       x = getattr(B, f1)(i)
       plt.plot(i, x)
   ...
```

`getattr(B, f1)` will return the function as in `B.f1`, and you call the function and pass the argument `i` with `(i)`, just like: `getattr(module, function)(*args)`.

For example: `getattr(plt, 'plot')(i, x)` = `plt.plot(i, x)`

Pay attention that you pass `plot` as string `'plot'`, so when you're trying to call function **A()**, you will do:

```
if __name__=='__main__':
    A('f62', 'f22', 'f2323', 'f100')
```

**As a side note:** if the function you pass is not in **B**, it will raise `AttributeError`.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you have the following defined in your interactive session

```
import B

def A(f1, f2, f3, f4):

    for i in range(10):
        plt.plot(i, f1(i))
```

And the user should call it by doing:

```
>>> A(B.f1, B.f49, B.f100, B.f42)
```